# MS Excel | how-to SUM combination of array/absolutevalue

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office

When using Microsoft Excel you can use the SUM function to add multiple cells, like so:

=SUM(A1:B7)

Let's say Row-A is an array set of numbers per cell (numbers totalled by formula) and Row-B is consisting of absolute values (4, 5, 6) in each cell.

The PROBLEM is using the SUM function when trying to add both array + absolutevalues. Otherwise it only works if I add either a set of array cells or a set of absolute cells, NOT both.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, I'm afraid. Perhaps you could add an illustrative dataset to your post to help clarify?

Comment: To my mind, I can see no reason why `SUM(A1:B7)` wouldn't work unless you are creating a *circular reference* by putting the formula into a cells that is referenced by the formula(s) in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem,

Having a sum-calculation of a whole column within a table formulated outside of the table had it cross-referenced it to a different format, like so:

Formula placed within table @cellA8:
=SUM(A1:A7)
Same formula used but placed outside of table @cellA9:
=SUM([column])

Using the formula created outside of table combined sum-function wouldn't calculate the table reference.